# ASP.Net WEB API AND ANGULAR Not outputting one column vs another

Tags: sql-server, angularjs, json

I was able to set up a asp.net web api and scaffolding to my sql server database. The return of the records from sql server appears to be JSON. The model has a few tables linked to each other by foreign keys and only has 2 records right now. Comp_Id = 1 and 2. The results to my local api looks like this:

> [{"ASSOC_INC_OFF":[{"OFFICERINVOLVEDs":[],"AIO_ID":1,"COMP_ID":1,"OFCNUM":1,"LINK_TYPE":null}],"CRITICALINCIDENTs":[{"CIType":"Physical Force resulting in Death or Serious Bodily Injury","CINotice":null,"CIMonitorRolledOut1":null,"CIDAMonitored":null,"CIOIMQuestions":null,"CICharged":null,"CIMonitor1":null,"CIMonitor2":null,"CINotes":null,"CIOfcCharges":null,"CIOutcome":null,"COMP_ID":1,"RolledOut_DT":null,"CI_ID":1,"CINotice_DT":"2016-01-07T00:00:00","CIOIMAllegNotes":null,"CIMonitorRolledOut2":null,"CIMonitorRolledOut3":null,"CIMonitorRolledOut4":null,"CIMonitorRolledOut5":null,"CIMonitorRolledOut6":null,"CIMonitorRolledOut7":null}],"COMP_ID":1,"FileNum":"case1","Received_DT":"2016-01-21T00:00:00","Completed_DT":null,"OIMIntake_DT":null,"Status":null,"Occurred_DT":null,"ComplaintType":null,"Source":"Chiefs Office","Precinct":"District 2","AddrCity":null,"AddrState":null,"AddrZip":null,"CaseSummary":null,"IABNotified_DT":null,"ClosureLetSent_DT":null,"CaseType":null,"OIMOutcome":null,"InitialFinding":null,"ClosedFindings":null,"OIMRecFinding":null,"timestamp":null,"Department":"DSD","Address":null,"DeclineReason":null,"Filenum2":null,"Filenum3":null,"OIMDiscRev_DT":null,"OIMInvRev_DT":null,"OIMInvRoute_DT":null,"OIMDiscRoute_DT":null,"CRORoute_DT":null},{"ASSOC_INC_OFF":[],"CRITICALINCIDENTs":[{"CIType":"Officer/Deputy-Involved Shooting","CINotice":null,"CIMonitorRolledOut1":null,"CIDAMonitored":null,"CIOIMQuestions":null,"CICharged":null,"CIMonitor1":null,"CIMonitor2":null,"CINotes":null,"CIOfcCharges":null,"CIOutcome":null,"COMP_ID":2,"RolledOut_DT":null,"CI_ID":2,"CINotice_DT":null,"CIOIMAllegNotes":null,"CIMonitorRolledOut2":null,"CIMonitorRolledOut3":null,"CIMonitorRolledOut4":null,"CIMonitorRolledOut5":null,"CIMonitorRolledOut6":null,"CIMonitorRolledOut7":null}],"COMP_ID":2,"FileNum":"cw1","Received_DT":"2016-01-03T00:00:00","Completed_DT":null,"OIMIntake_DT":null,"Status":"Active","Occurred_DT":null,"ComplaintType":null,"Source":"Citizen Walk-in","Precinct":"District 7","AddrCity":null,"AddrState":null,"AddrZip":null,"CaseSummary":null,"IABNotified_DT":null,"ClosureLetSent_DT":null,"CaseType":"District-Bureau","OIMOutcome":"Satisfactory","InitialFinding":"Formal","ClosedFindings":null,"OIMRecFinding":"Decline","timestamp":null,"Department":"DSD","Address":null,"DeclineReason":"Body Worn Camera","Filenum2":null,"Filenum3":null,"OIMDiscRev_DT":null,"OIMInvRev_DT":null,"OIMInvRoute_DT":null,"OIMDiscRoute_DT":null,"CRORoute_DT":null}]

I am able to bind COMP_ID to my view but when I add in CIType, nothings appears.

console.log($scope.complaints) returns:

[image]

My Controller looks like this:

```
app.controller('UpdateController', function ($scope, ComplaintService) {

getCities();

function getCities() {
    ComplaintService.getCities()
        .success(function (complaints) {
            $scope.complaints = complaints;

        })
        .error(function (error) {
            $scope.status = 'Unable to load customer data: ' + error.message;

        });
}
});
```

My service looks like this:

```
app.factory('ComplaintService', ['$http', function ($http){
var urlBase = 'http://localhost:63942/api';
var ComplaintService = {};
ComplaintService.getCities = function () {
    return $http.get(urlBase+ '/complaints');
};
return ComplaintService;
```

}]);

and my index looks like this:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-3" ng-controller="UpdateController">
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>CI TYPE</th>
        <tr ng-repeat="a in complaints">
            <td>{{a.COMP_ID}}</td>
            <td>{{a.CIType }}</td>

    </table>
</div>
```

I am certainly confused about why I can render out only COMPID but not the rest of this api contents as it is all listed under localhost:###/api/complaints.

Comment: looking trough your json was pretty hard, try to do console.log($scope.complaints) (use devtools to see it), to see how the objects actually look like.

Comment: Thanks @thsorens, I did that and it says that I have Array[2] with two objects. Apparently, there are the other tables listed like a subset Array of the Main object, for each table. Is there a method for accessing that "sub array"? The reason, why I call it a subset, because you have to expand it by clicking on the carrot.

Comment: as long as its json, you can always just . yourself down to it. If the goal is to make everything go into one list, you might have to push each result in the differrent sub-lists into a new list that you use to display

Comment: @thsorens, I uploaded a snapshot of what the console log looks like. How would I . myself down to the Assoc_INC.OFF and CriticalIncidents?  Thank you.

Comment: i added an example, my es4 syntax is a bit out of shape, but i think it gives some pointers

Comment: @thsorens, thank you. I will have to give this some thought as I am a beginner in these two languages. Can you add this outside of your controller or would you create a new javscript file to use it?

Comment: you can add it inside your controller. any javascript can pretty much be executed within the controller. To make it available in the view, put it into the scope:) And the other way around, you dont want to put data that shouldnt be available in the view in the scope, since it will bloat your scope, which might lead to performance issues later on.

Answer (score 0):

```
var someResultArray = [];


$scope.complaints.forEach(function(elem){
    //basically checks if this exists in the object to avoid undefined issues
    if(elem.ASSOC_INF_OFF){
        elem.ASSOC_INF_OFF.forEach(function(assoc){
            //do something with each assoc, ex: push it to another array
             someResultArray.push(assoc);
        });
    } 
});
```

an object in javascript can be treated by dotting yourself down, or you can also address its content by index, even though its an object. So you could write elem["ASSOC_INF_OFF"], and it would still work.